Blazor and HMTX: form only get
I have a project in ASP.NET Core 8. This project has HTMX. Now, I want to add Blazor to the solution. I have quite a simple page that mimics the example on GitHub.
<CascadingValue Value="ValidationResult">
    <form id="counter" hx-post="slacktest/ui" hx-swap="outerHTML" 
        hx-target="#counter">
        <HtmxAntiforgeryToken/>
        <input type="hidden" id="check" value="@SlackForm.Check" />
        <input type="text" value="@SlackForm.SubscribeId" 
               name="@nameof(SlackForm.SubscribeId)" 
               class="form-control-plaintext w-100"/>
        <label class="w-100">
            Slack
            <InputText @bind-Value="SlackForm.WebhookUrl" 
                name="@nameof(SlackForm.WebhookUrl)"/>
            <HtmxValidationMessage For="() => SlackForm.WebhookUrl"/>
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
    </form>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public SlackUIModel SlackForm { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public ValidationResult ValidationResult { get; set; } = new();
}

I added the minimal APIs for this page in the Program.cs. The issue is that every time I click the button, the request from the form is to the GET. There is no way to send a request as a POST.
Do you have any idea if this is related to a configuration of the project or something related to the HTMX working with Blazor?

It wouldn't huurt to be specific:  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>

But otherwise, elaborate on what you can see in the network tab.

Try removing hx-post="slacktest/ui" hx-swap="outerHTML" from your form element, and updating your button to:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" hx-post="slacktest/ui" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#counter"> Click me </button>
This is because, by default a button on a form is of type submit, and submit defaults to a GET request if the url is defined on the form...
Your HTMX is intercepting the form submission payload, but not the submit execution.  By defining the button as type button you are now intercepting the default execution, and the hx-post and hx-target are intercepting the payload.
If this still doesn't work, please post the body of your program.cs which contains your APIs.
